# Output a list of ids in which the number of zeros at the end is greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe. The name of the columns is the store id. I need to get a list of store ids whose number of zeros from the end is greater equal to 3

| 76 | 123 | 872 | 987 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Here's what I'm waiting for at the exit: [76,987]
Could you help me?

I'm a beginner, and I tried to create loops, and the only thing I managed was to count the total number of zeros. But i  need the number of zeros running in a row from the end. And if there are more than 3 of them, then get a list of IDs at the output. Please help me.

Comment: Try this: list(df.columns[df.iloc[-3:,:].sum() == 0])

Comment: Basically we take the last 3 rows, check which columns have sum of last 3 rows equal to 0. Should return your desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

I have commented the code for the bits that i needed to do...

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {76:[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     123:[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     872:[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     987:[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


# Convert to numeric columns
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

# Filter columns where last 3 rows are 0  
mask = df.iloc[-3:,].eq(0).all()
df_filtered = df.loc[:, mask]


# Print the just the columns
print(df_filtered.columns.tolist())
```

Which will return this:

```
[76, 987]
```

Comment: you are welcome.  there are a few different ways to achieve this, but this was relatively consise.